# How to force https on certain URL only on Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

On my spring security application, we are using the java config as below. I want to configure https only for those URL with pattern mydomain.com/secure/etc. However other url pattern should remain insecure which is HTTP. Following are my codes in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/non-secure/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasAuthority("user")
    .and()
    .requiresChannel()
    .antMatchers("/secure/**").requiresSecure()
```

I'm supposed only secure for the url with pattern mydomain.com/secure/etc.

However using the configuration above, all the pages in the system are redirected to `https` including `/non-secure/**` instead of only those matches. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following instead?

```
http
 .authorizeRequests()
 .antMatchers("/non-secure/**").permitAll()
 .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasAuthority("user")
 .and().requiresChannel().antMatchers("/non-secure/**").requiresInsecure()
 .and().requiresChannel().antMatchers("/secure/**").requiresSecure()
```